# Logical Operators expression to a PHP array

Tags: php, logical-operators

I have expressions like this =>
({2606} OR {2549} OR {2543} OR ({2605} AND {2562})) AND ({2387} OR {2383} OR {1990} OR {2412} OR {2411} OR {2409} OR ({2408} AND {2593}))

I want output like this Array.

[

```
"AND" => [ 

     "OR" => [ 2606, 2549, 2543, "AND" => [ 2605, 2562 ] ],
     "OR" => [ 2387, 2383, 1990, 2412, 2411, 2409, "AND" => [ 2408, 2593 ] ]
 ]
```

]

Need a php script for this.

Comment: What is this **({2606} OR {2549} OR {2543} OR ({2605} AND {2562})) AND ({2387} OR {2383} OR {1990} OR {2412} OR {2411} OR {2409} OR ({2408} AND {2593}))** array? string? something else??

Comment: If you want a script, why don't you write it?

Comment: @SiderTopalov This will be a string.

Comment: @Dominique I was stuck somewhere and wanted guidance. Something you can tell verbally So I can start with this. This is kind of a nested logical operations. Something I couldnt do myself. Still trying though.

Comment: That is a pretty poor structure, what you need is this `['groupOp' => 'AND', 'items' =>[ [ 'field' => 'someField', 'op' => 'in', 'data' => [1,2,3,4]], 'group' => [...]]` where `group` is a recursive copy of this and `op` can be anything from `nn` (not null) to `be` (Begins with) etc.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I can review the structure. Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me how can I process this type of strings to any understandable structure. I was thinking that I should go by presedence and replace that part by an Alphabet 'A' and then have its processed part in '$A' And then so on. Dont know How can I explain that better.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have written the script. Thats what I wanted, In case I couldnt put my question properly. Appreciate your concern.
http://www.dijitalbrains.org/temp/logical_operators.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$rule = "({2606} OR {2549} OR {2543} OR ({2605} AND {2562})) AND ({2387} OR {2383} OR {1990} OR {2412} OR {2411} OR {2409} OR ({2408} AND {2593}))";
$previous_rule = '';

// Clean Curly Braces and Trim is there's a space.
$rule = trim( str_replace( array( "{", "}" ) , "", $rule ) );

echo "INPUT: " . $rule . "<br><br>";

foreach( range('a', 'z') as $letter ){

    $substituted_part = "(". substitution( $rule ) . ")";

    $$letter = $substituted_part;

    $rule = str_replace( $substituted_part, $letter, $rule );

    if( $previous_rule != $rule )
        $previous_rule = $rule;
    else
        break;

}

echo "<PRE>";
print_r( replaceOriginal($rule) );

function replaceOriginal( $rule ){

    if( preg_match("/[a-z]/i", $rule) ){

        if( strpos( $rule, "AND" ) !== false )
            $processed_rule = array( "AND" => explode(" AND ", $rule ) );

        else if( strpos( $rule, "OR" ) !== false )
            $processed_rule = array( "OR" => explode(" OR ", $rule ) );

        foreach( $processed_rule as $operator => $values ){

            $processed_rule[$operator] = process( $values );
        }

        return $processed_rule;

    }

}

function process( $values ){

    foreach( $values as $key => $value ){

        if( !empty( $GLOBALS[$value] ) ){

            $substituted_value = str_replace( array( "(", ")" ) , "", $GLOBALS[$value] );

            $values[$key] = replaceOriginal( $substituted_value );;

        }

    }

    return $values;
}

function substitution( $rule ){

    // Get anything thats wrapped in parentheses.
    if( preg_match_all('#\((([^()]+|(?R))*)\)#', $rule, $matches) ){

        foreach( $matches[1] as $value ){
            return substitution( $value );
        }

    }else{

        return $rule;
    }
}
```